# Can CMake custom help text(like AC_ARG_WITH)?

Tags: cmake

When I need a option in autoconf, I just add `AC_ARG_WITH`( or `AC_ARG_ENABLE`) to `configure.ac`:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([readline],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-readline],
    [support fancy command line editing @<:@default=check@:>@])],
    [],
    [with_readline=check])
```

the help text will be:

```
--with-readline         support fancy command line editing [default=check]
```

Well, How to do this in cmake?

*I can add `-D` option to compile, but how to show help text?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [option()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) command that declares bool variable and sets description text for it.

There is no way to show it with `cmake` command, but you can run `cmake-gui` or `ccmake`, which display all options along with descriptions.